# Python pandas and oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Have tried below code for the first time. Need to insert data from pandas data frame to oracle database. 
But am getting below error. Could any one guide me?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0))


query ="INSERT INTO invoice_header_mapping (column1,column2)" \
       "VALUES(%S,%S)"
args = (df.column1,df.column2)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query,args)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ETL.py", line 22, in <module>
    cur.execute(query,args)
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type Series
```

Thank you

Comment: I think you are using mysql syntax and not oracle. Look at this site for example and find the keyword "executemany".  https://learncodeshare.net/2015/06/26/insert-crud-using-cx_oracle/

Answer (score 0):

I can point some guidelines to try and solve the issue at hand:

It seems the type of data you are passing is not supported (try perharps args = (df.column1.values,df.column2.values)), if numpy arrays are not supported also, convert it to list.

If that also fails, check if the cursor has a method like "executemany", and try again.